# Trace Unauthorized login into My Gmail and Facebook Account

Tags: authentication, passwords, email, logging, facebook

I have experienced an unauthorized login into my Gmail and Facebook account, while I was logging into the accounts and doing school assignments. Suddenly, I got an email from Facebook about "***303231123127639 is your Facebook account recovery code***". And my Gmail and Facebook passwords are changed. I immediately changed both my Gmail and Facebook passwords.

But I still got the information of the unauthorized login. So my question is that with the IP address provided from unauthorized login, can I trace who the f**k logged into my account. Is there any website or tool that I can know to trace the one who logged in to my account and changed my password?

Screenshots of the incident:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

How to find out who the hell is trying to log in to my account?

by the way, I am an IT student from Thailand, and would like to know more about the security.

Comment: You'd have to ask the ISP that provided Internet access to that IP who it belongs to.

Comment: You're basically asking if you can track a person based on IP address. The answer to this is generally speaking no, and reasons are given in for instance [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/94340/how-to-track-back-a-dynamic-ip-address)

Comment: How certain are you that the original email ("_This is your account recovery code_") was genuine? Could it have been a phishing email taking you to a fake site to "reset" your passwords? For either or both services, did you check that your original passwords no longer worked?